# Check ruby gem and SQLite3 for FTS3 or FTS4 support

Tags: sqlite

I have installed SQLite3 on Mountain Lion via MacPorts and Ruby along with *sqlite3* gem using RVM.

I'd like to know if there's any way for me to understand if my SQLite3 installation supports [FTS4](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

i.e. The only way I found online was issuing FTS3 commands and not getting errors, but there must be a more 'clean' way... Also the mentioned way doesn't show if you have FTS3 or 4 working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states:

> Note that enabling FTS3 also makes FTS4 available. There is not a
>   separate SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 compile-time option. A build of SQLite
>   either supports both FTS3 and FTS4 or it supports neither.

So if FTS3 works, so does FTS4.

Doesn't look like it's possible to tell what options sqlite was compiled with [according to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881370/way-to-find-out-which-compilation-options-were-used-to-build-sqlite).